# Type-level flattening of a heterogenous Tree

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am learning Shapeless and have implemented a simple heterogenous tree

I would like to be able to extract the labels with type information retained. I tried hard but haven't even got a sketch of a solution to present. Any help appreciated!

```scala
object TreeTest {

  import shapeless._

  case class HTree[A, F <: HList](label: A, forest: F) {
    def withBranch[T, FF <: HList](tree: HTree[T, FF]): HTree[A, HTree[T, FF] :: F] = new HTree(label, tree :: forest)
  }

  object HTree {
    def apply[A](label: A) = new HTree[A, HNil](label, HNil)
  }

  val t1 = HTree(1)
  val t2 = HTree("1")
  val t3 = t2.withBranch(HTree(2.0))
  val t4: HTree[Int, HTree[String, HTree[Double, HNil] :: HNil] :: HNil] = t1.withBranch(t3)

  def labels[A, F <: HList](t: HTree[A, F]) = ???

  val flattened: Int :: String :: Double :: HNil = labels(t4)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to create a recursive polymorphic function to extract the labels of your `HTree` :

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist._

object getLabels extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseHTree[A, F <: HList, M <: HList](implicit 
    fm: FlatMapper.Aux[getLabels.type, F, M],
    prepend: Prepend[A :: HNil, M]
  ) : Case.Aux[HTree[A, F], prepend.Out] = 
    at[HTree[A, F]](tree => prepend(tree.label :: HNil, fm(tree.forest)))
}
```

It prepends the label of the current `HTree` to the labels of the branches which it gets recursively (flatmapping over `forest`).

Which gives for `t4` :

```
getLabels(t4)
// Int :: String :: Double :: HNil = 1 :: 1 :: 2.0 :: HNil
```